# OpenGL ES Tutorial - 'Winmain': function cannot be overloaded

Tags: visual-studio, opengl-es, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn OpenGL ES with the "OpenGL ES Training Course" (An OpenGL ES tutorial). I use OPENGL-ES 1.1 WINDOWS PC EMULATION with visual studio 2010. I'm trying to compile the 'hello triangle' program and get an error:

> 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded

EDIT: I have only one definition of WinMain in the project: The one in the 'hello triangle' source code (which I didn't write).

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two definitions of `WinMain`, or perhaps a prototype and a definition that disagree.

Comment: Thanks, but I have one wiWinMain definition (edited my question). What do you mean by 'a prototype and a definition that disagree'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too. It showed that I have overloaded the function:
My old text:

```
#include "windows.h"

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, long lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{

}
```

and my new text:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

With the new text it works

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

    // Your Code.

}
```

Instead Of

```
int WinMain(){

    // Your Code.

}
```